# A simple graph is 2-connected iff for every x,y,z in $V(G)$, $G$ has an $x$-$z$ path through $y$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

This is problem 4.2.8 in introduction to graph theory by West.

Prove that a simple graph $G$ is 2-connected if and only if for every triple $(x,y,z)$ of distinct vertices, $G$ has an $x,z$-path through $y$.

The forward direction is easy because if it is 2 connected its connected so theres a path from $x$ to $y$ and a path from $y$ to $z$ so putting them together gives a path.

I dont see how the other direction goes except to think try to show there is a simple cycle containing x and z from the assumption. Tips would be appreciated and this is not homework its just self study.

Comment: Your proof of the forward direction doesn't pass muster -- how do you know that your path from $x$ to $y$ doesn't include $z$?  This is a property that isn't generally true of connected graphs, so you should expect that you have to make actual use of 2-connectedness.

Comment: Ok but there are at least two vertex disjoint paths from x to y so at least one doesnt use z. similarly two from y to z so at least one doesnt use x. This is correct right?

Comment: You still have to contemplate the fact that even having chosen the paths that avoid the necessary vertices, those paths can intersect.

Comment: Oh your right. Ill think about this some more. thanks

Comment: You are asked to prove that "G is 2-connected" iff (S). You think you've proved the forward direction by proving that "G is connected" implies (S), and you are stuck trying to prove that (S) implies "G is 2-connected". If you could also do that, then you would have proved that "G is connected" implies "G is 2-connected", nicht wahr? Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Yeah i see my error now, thank you

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $x$ is a vertex whose removal disconnects the graph; there must be vertices $y$ and $z$ that are in distinct components of $G-x$. Can there be an $x,z$ path through $y$? (I’m assuming that by *path* you mean *simple path*.)

Comment: Any path from one component of G-x to another would have to go through x because if there was a way around it then G-x would not be disconnected because that path would still exist in G-x. right?

Comment: @user99727: That’s what I had in mind, yes.

Comment: thanks! The hardest part for intro graph theory seems to be deciding what proof method to try... i think i just need to practice a lot haha

Comment: @user99727: You’re welcome! When the desired conclusion is a universal statement (e.g., for **every** triple ...), it’s often easiest to prove the contrapositive or use a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Could the forward direction be proven by using induction?
Base case: n=3, so $\delta(G) \ge 2 > n/2$, hence we can say by Dirac that G is Hamiltonian.
Assume true for $3,..., n-1$.
Now add a vertex $v$ to G which is adjacent to $x$ and $z$. Now we get two cycles and 3 paths between $x$ and $z$. On one of them $y$ has to be included.
Or did I make this too easy?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This proof by induction does not cover all possible $2$-connected graphs. For example, a $2$-connected graph in which $x$ and $z$ have no common neighbor will never be obtained this way.

Comment: If you really want to know if this proof strategy can be made to work, you shouldn't be answering questions: you should be posting your own question asking for feedback about this proof.